# date select field sends wrong value in logs, not the one I selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Working on a credit card payment system on my app. I have a field `card_expires_on` that is divided into 2 selects:

```
<%= f.date_select :card_expires_on, {:discard_day => true, discard_year: true, :add_month_numbers => true}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
```

and

```
<%= f.date_select :card_expires_on, {:discard_day => true, discard_month: true, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => (Date.today.year+10)}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
```

one for month, one for year. If I select a year that's different from the current one rails sends the right(selected) value, but when I change the month to something else than the current one, it sends the current month anyway in logs.

```
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {..., "order"=>{..., "card_expires_on(3i)"=>"1", "card_expires_on(2i)"=>"9", "card_expires_on(1i)"=>"2016", "package_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Confirm Purchase"}
```

As you can see in `"card_expires_on(2i)"=>"9"`, month number is the current one, but I selected december. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same field name for both, so the second (the year field) is overwriting the first.  Since you're discarding the month on the year field, it's probably just returning the current month.

Give unique names and see if that fixes it:

```
:card_expires_on_month
:card_expires_on_year
```

Comment: This is the way date fields works in rails, if you see the logs assigns `3i`, `2i`, `1i` to each part of a date attribute and merge it when saving the record so I have a date, month and year in one field in database like `2016-09-01`, no need to have different fields. Thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah right.  But isn't that only if you let Rails split it up for you automatically by using from f.date_select?

Comment: Meaning if you just use it once, shouldn't Rails automatically create the 2 fields and avoid the problem I mentioned?

Comment: May be you got a point here, it used to be in one f.select `<%= f.date_select :card_expires_on, :discard_day => true, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => (Date.today.year+10), :add_month_numbers => true %>` this generates 2 selects, one for month and one for year, but logs were exactly the same before. Plus, I need them separate for styling purposes.